# How to set material for metal(like silver) in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, lighting

How to set material for metal(like silver) in OpenGL? Anyone knows?

Comment: Why not use a metal texture you find online and apply it to your object?

Comment: Shaders + texturing.. and if you're feeling brave then ray tracing too.

Comment: You don't just call `glEnable(GL_METAL)`. Mimicking metal, or *any* real-world substance, is a complex thing, which can be approximated in various ways to get varying degrees of accuracy. Because of that, there's no way to answer this question without knowing more about the scope of the overall problem.

Comment: @Chris911: "Why not use a metal texture" Because texture isn't shiny.

Answer (score 7):

> How to set material for metal(like silver) in OpenGL? Anyone knows?

If you want your material to sometimes look "kinda" like metal, you need to set corresponding diffuse, ambient, specular and "shininess" parameters. You could investigate existing material libraries for 3d editors like [blender](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Every_Material_Known_to_Man/Realistic_Silver) and see how they do it. That's cheap, but it will also look cheap. Normally material with low GL_SHININESS value (3..12, I think?) will look "kinda" like metallic surface.

If you want your material to look more like metal, but under certain lighting condition, you'll need to write pixel shader that will use photorealistic texture of silver, additional texture map that controls specular color and strength. A good texture allows you to get away with horrible and easy shader, as long as lighting conditions were carefully selected. That requires programmer with GLSL knowledge and a good artist to make texture, and artist will be more important - even a non-metallic shader like per-pixel phong can be fine-tuned by hand to look like what you want (precess might be boring and tedious). Shader itself only requires per-pixel lighting with specular (any specular), normalmapping support and environmental reflection mapping (with fresnel term support). Using HDR for weakly-reflective polished surfaces will also help.

If you want REAL and PERFECT silver, then you're in trouble and should reconsider. Metallic surfaces have "fuzzy" reflections that can be a pain to implement quickly, depending on your hardware. Another problem is that you'll have to pretty much study the metal itself, check every metallic surface demo that exists out there, read GDC papers, etc. I.e. do the research, which can take a lot of time/effort and won't pay off in the end because it is quite possible that final result will have horrible performance. The important thing is that you don't need to simulate real material to make it look right - you need to fool the viewer into thinking that this is silver.

Answer (score 5):

If you check [this site](http://devernay.free.fr/cours/opengl/materials.html) you can find a selection of different material settings designed to mimic various materials, including silver.  However, as others have said in comments, remember that Phong shading, which is what OpenGL uses material settings like this to do, has a hard time rendering certain real-world substances in a realistic manner, particularly reflective ones like silver.  But the material settings at that site should give you something silver-like, at least to a first approximation.  (Make sure you catch the note at the end about multiplying shininess by 128)

Answer (score 0):

As Solaraeus says, you can make a  "material" class to defining a material objects, for example:

```
#ifndef _MATERIAL
#define _MATERIAL
#include <GL/gl.h>

class material{

  private:

    GLfloat ambient_r;
    GLfloat ambient_g;
    GLfloat ambient_b;

    GLfloat diffuse_r;
    GLfloat diffuse_g;
    GLfloat diffuse_b;

    GLfloat specular_r;
    GLfloat specular_g;
    GLfloat specular_b;


public:

    material(GLfloat ar, GLfloat ag, GLfloat ab, GLfloat dr, GLfloat dg, GLfloat db, GLfloat sr, GLfloat sg, GLfloat sb){
        ambient_r=ar;   ambient_g=ag;   ambient_b=ab;
        diffuse_r=dr;   diffuse_g=dg;   diffuse_b=db;
        specular_r=sr;  specular_g=sg;  specular_b=sb;
    }

    void active(){
        GLfloat ambient[]={ambient_r, ambient_g, ambient_b, 1.0};
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
        GLfloat diffuse[]={diffuse_r, diffuse_g, diffuse_b};
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
        GLfloat specular[]={specular_r, specular_g, specular_b};
        glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, specular);
    }
};

#endif
```

After you can define a file .h with several materials for later use, for example:

```
#ifndef _MATERIALS
#define _MATERIALS
#include "material.h"

                        // ### specification of materials ### //

material turquesa(0.1, 0.18725, 0.1745, 0.396, 0.74151, 0.69102, 0.297254, 0.30829, 0.306678);
material esmeralda(0.0215, 0.1745, 0.0215, 0.07568, 0.61424, 0.07568, 0.633, 0.727811, 0.633);
material jade(0.135, 0.2225, 0.1575, 0.54, 0.89, 0.63, 0.316228, 0.316228, 0.316228);
material obsidian(0.05375, 0.05, 0.06625, 0.18275, 0.17, 0.22525, 0.332741, 0.328634, 0.346435);
//more and more...
```

#endif

So you can use them anywhere including materials.h activating the material when you need it:

Example:

```
#include "materials.h"
...
...
turquesa.active();

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            for(unsigned i=0; i<faces.size(); i++){
                glNormal3f(x, y, z); 
                glVertex3f(x, y, z);
                glVertex3f(x, y, z);
                glVertex3f(x, y, z); 
            }
        glEnd();
...
...
```

Is easier if you think about objects.

Answer (score 0):

High quality metallic appearance can be obtained using  PBR - Physically Based Rendering - techniques.
Basically, PBR use a shader and the following texture inputs:

- Albedo (diffuse) color;
- Normal map;
- roughness - map surface roughness/smoothness;
- metalness - a map surface for metal / no metal areas;

There are plenty or articles about PBR on Web. One of may favourites is this [one](https://www.marmoset.co/posts/pbr-texture-conversion/).

Also, combined with a environmental effect (Cube map or other reflection technique) highlights the metal effect.